# Why is std::seed_seq::generate not const?

Tags: c++, std, random-seed

When calling [`std::seed_seq::generate(begin, end)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq/generate) multiple times on the same `seed_seq` object, I get the same numbers every time (this is in contrast to a random number generator, which always advances its state after producing output). So apparently the state of the `seed_seq` object is unchanged. But why is the `.generate(begin, end)` function not marked as `const`?

Comment: Your conclusion doesn’t match your observation. Determinism is not the same as const-ness.

Comment: @sweenish True. But generally speaking, everything that can be const should be const. So I was wondering if there a technical reason why this isnt? It seems very easy to implement it in a way that does guarantee const-ness.

Comment: The internal state changes, but does so deterministically. How do you make that const?

Comment: @sweenish No, the state of the seed_seq does not change at all. At least not in an observable way. Calling generate() a second time produces the same output as the first call. The internal state is not "advanced", like it would be with random-number generators.

Comment: @sweenish it's certainly [possible to implement it](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/8b29b84c99ac8140c9820fd34b733bdedf5bb0f5/libcxx/include/__random/seed_seq.h#L88) without modifying any internal state

Comment: It would help to alleviate confusion, if you mention, that generate takes two iterators as output range.

Comment: note that the named requirement SeedSequence says that calls to `generate` potentially depend on previous calls to `generate`. Ie in general SeedSequences `generate` cannot be `const`.